# Is it possible to disable automatic empty value insertion for fields without default value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null, default-value

Is there any configuration setting to stop MySQL from inserting an empty value for fields which don't have a default value and weren't specified in the insert statement? **I'd much prefer it rejected an invalid insert statement.**

Example - I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `val1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `val2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

If you run this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO test (val2) VALUES('a');
```

You get this response:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Response from `show warnings`:

```
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'val1' doesn't have a default value |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Response from `SELECT * FROM test`:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | val1 | val2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |      | asdf |
+----+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable ['strict' mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables), which'd cause MySQL to fail any inserts that don't provide values for default-less fields.